# Выбор категорий на jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Начну с предисловия: Мой сайт - это платформа для продажи цифровых товаров. Есть несколько категорий.
http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/07/03/989/0a2/e9233811acce928ef442ab2a4f7f73d49d5f6570.jpg

Требуется сделать что-то вроде распределения категорий в зависимости от того, какие категории выбраны пользователем. Что-то подобное
http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/07/03/805/c39/bd2f3af51b619756395daeff9388da7ec8b9f303.jpg

Но беда в том, что, если снять все галки в обратном порядке из базы (которой является поле type="hidden") ID категорий не удаляются.

Вот код категорий:

```
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(1);">ВКонтакте<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_1"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(2);">Одноклассники<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_2"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(3);">Facebook<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_3"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(4);">Twitter<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_4"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(5);">Instagram<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_5"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(7);">Steam<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_7"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(6);">Origin<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_6"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(11);">Minecraft<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_11"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(9);">Почты<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_9"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(12);">Купоны<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_12"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(10);">Dedicated server<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_10"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
<div class="href_nav_main" onclick="_index._nav(8);">Прочие аккаунты<div class="checked_ico checked_ico_8"><img src="/images/checked.png"></div></div>
```

Вот код функции `_index._nav()`

```
_nav: function(id) {
        if($(this).attr('dde') == 0 || $(this).attr('dde') == null) {

            if($('#href_nav_main_base').val() == '') {
             $('.centerBoxContentsFeatured').fadeOut(0);
            }
            $('#href_nav_main_base').val($('#href_nav_main_base').val()+','+id);
            setTimeout(function() {
             $('#href_nav_main_base').val($('#href_nav_main_base').val().replace(/^,/, ''));
            }, 5);
            $('.checked_ico_'+id).addClass('active_ch');
            $('[t_type = '+id+']').fadeIn(0);
            $(this).attr('dde', '1');
        } else {
         $('#href_nav_main_base').val($('#href_nav_main_base').val()
       .replace(id, '')
       .replace(/^,/, '')
       .replace(/,$/, '')
       );
            if($('#href_nav_main_base').val() == '') {
             $('.centerBoxContentsFeatured').fadeIn(0);
            } else {
             $('[t_type = '+id+']').fadeOut(0);
            }
         $('.checked_ico_'+id).removeClass('active_ch');
            $(this).attr('dde', '0');
        }
    }
```

Другого, более простого варианта не придумал. Буду рад выслушать Ваши идеи по данному вопросу.

Comment: @Виктор Евлампьев прочитал ваш вопрос несколько раз так и не пойму что вы хотите чтобы происходило или не происходило?

Comment: @pvkovalev 

    Но беда в том, что, если снять все галки в обратном порядке из базы (которой является поле type="hidden") ID категорий не удаляются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо, если я правильно всё понял (в чем я не уверен :-) ), то проблема в сохранении в поле '#href_nav_main_base' выбранных категорий. Если вообще не менять ваш код, то я бы посоветовал сделать примерно так

```
_nav: function (id) {
    if ($(this).attr('dde') == 0 || $(this).attr('dde') == null) {
        // Тра ля ля 
        var ab = '';
        $('div.active_ch').each(function () {
            var currentValue = (($(this).parent().attr("onclick")).replace("_index._nav(", "")).replace(");", "");
            if (ab !== '') {
                ab = ab + ','
            }
            ab = ab + currentValue
        })
        //alert(ab);
        $('#href_nav_main_base').val(ab);
        // Тра ля ля 
    }
}
```

Т.е. упростить задачу до перебора всех отмеченых элементов я проверял на [speedsell.ru](http://speedsell.ru/) и у меня всё сработало. Было бы конечно проще если бы был какой-то аттрибут с этим самым CategoryId.
Дайте знать если это помогло. Удачи!